# Static font files not served in Vite dev environnement

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-9, laravel-valet

I am trying to switch from webpack to vite in an existing Laravel application. For local development I use Laravel Valet.

If I run `vite build` everything works correctly (images, fonts, scss), but if I run `vite` the only bug I get is that it doesn't get the fonts path correctly (Error 404):

```
https://example.test:5173/fonts/open-sans/regular-400.woff2
```

Without the port it would work.

I've read a lot and I think I've tried everything:

Attempts (failed) in the Vite configuration:

```
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {

    return {
        // root: './',
        // base: './',
        // publicDir: 'public',
        // assetsInclude: ['public/fonts'],

        // Rest of the configuration are Plugins (Laravel, Vue), Alias etc...            
    }
});
```

So I try to change the `root`, `base`, `publicDir` nor `assetsInclude` and don't remember what else... and nothing of them hasn't solved my problem.

The structure of my public folder:

```
- public
  - build
    - assets
  - fonts
  - images
```

css font-face:

```
@font-face {
    ...
    url('/fonts/open-sans/regular-400.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/fonts/open-sans/regular-400.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Comment: Late comment, but the problem is that the CSS is being served by Vite on 5173, so any relative URLs in the CSS will be calculated relative to that, not to your app.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to add the alias for the font path (`public/font`) only in the dev environment:

```
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {

    const alias = {
       (some alias),       
    };

    // dev environment
    if (command === 'serve') {
        Object.assign(alias, { '/fonts': path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/fonts') });
    }
    
    return {
        ...
        resolve: {
            alias
       }
    }
});
```

I think it's a Vite bug and I don't know if that's the best solution for that, so I'm open to any suggestions.